# red-black tree deletion idea is wrong?

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree

The most complicated case is as shown in figure. The node needs to be deleted and the its son are all black. But how could this happen? 
I mean from the view of the node N, the route goes left has definitely one more black node than the route goes right. So this case is actually not possible? The only possible scene is the black node with a red son, if the node has a single child.

Did I misunderstand something or the whole r-b tree deletion is wrong?

[image]

Comment: A node with a single black child can't happen in a valid red-black tree, but some deletion algorithms may *temporarily* create that situation, and fix it up in a later step.

Comment: @MattTimmermans hi matt, I think the process described in wiki and CLRS both indicate that we just need to copy the value of the predecessor/successor into the "originally to deleted node", then just delete the predecessor/successor. So the color of the predecessor/successor has not been changed. Or did I misunderstand this process?

Comment: That swapping thing is just the first step.  If you swap the node you want to delete with a black node, then you have to delete the black node... but deleting a black node will create an invalid tree that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @MattTimmermans hey matt, I got it now. The case discussion of r-b tree(at least the one from wikipedia) actually regards a situation of two NIL as children is regarded as "single black child". This is also the only possibility. That means, the whole idea discussed the case of deleting a node with two NIL children...